# MTOUCH : error MT2001: Could not link assemblies

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, build, azure-pipelines

```
MTOUCH : error MT2001: Could not link assemblies.

    Type: `Xamarin.Essentials.AuthManager`

    Assembly: `Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

  Reason: Value cannot be null.

  Parameter name: key
```

I am getting the above error when building a Xamarin.Forms solution on Azure DevOps pipelines.
The pipeline runs into the error when building the iOS project. It started to break when I updated to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms v4.5.0.530 and Xamarin.Essentials v1.5.2. When I run the build locally on VS Mac it builds fine.

If anyone can help that would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Try to clear your solution locally and  then build locally again

Comment: The solution builds locally fine. It fails only within DevOps pipeline

Comment: What OS your host agent use?

Comment: Do you have any build tasks in devops that set the xcode version and xamarin sdk versions? I had this happen today when re-hydrating a pipeline after 6 months absent, turned out it just needed the xcode version updated from 10.1 to 11.3.1, and the xamarin version updated from 5.16 to 6.8.

Comment: @Mike sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 6_6_0_166 I'm using this script but now I'm getting "MSBuild or xbuild (Mono) were not found on the macOS or Linux agent." error when trying to build my Xamarin UI test project within the pipeline

Comment: I am using the "macOS-10.14" image

Comment: @SachK, How about build it with `macOS-10.15` image? And try to turn off Xaml Compilation:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77711/could-not-link-assemblies-reason-value-cannot-be-null-mt2001?

Comment: @SachK, I've expanded on my comment with an answer that worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error message in azure devops after updating a project to the latest.  I suspect it's something to do with the newer 10.15 macos agents, but resolving it was just a case of updating everything to use latest.

Specifically, I had 2 tasks at the start of the job like the below (psuedo code btw)

`Select Xamarin SDK Version:
sudo $(Agent.HomeDirectory)/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 5_16_0`


`Select Xcode version:
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_10.1.app/Contents/Developer`

The resolution was to update the Xamarin SDK version to 6.8 and the xcode version to 11.3.1, so now I had 2 tasks like this:

`Select Xamarin SDK Version:
sudo $(Agent.HomeDirectory)/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 6_8_0`


`Select Xcode version:
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer`

I also set the agent specifically to the 10.15 version  in the job config using

- 'Azure Pipelines' as the Agent Pool
- 'macOS-10.15' as the Agent Specification

and in the 'Demands' section, made sure that it had 'exists' demands for the following

- xcode
- Xamarin.iOS

Hope that helps.  I'm by no means an expert in this stuff, this just worked for me :)

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've tried to update the image to - macOS -10.15 and added the select XCode and Xamarin SDK scripts however still getting the 'MSBuild or xbuild (Mono) were not found on the macOS or Linux agent.' error :(

Comment: if you export the yaml for the pipeline, does it start with something like this?
`pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands:
  - xcode
  - Xamarin.iOS
`

Comment: pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands:
  - xcode
  - msbuild
  - MSBuild
  - Xamarin.Android
  - JDK
  - Xamarin.iOS - This is the start of my build pipeline. However I don't think the demands has anything to do with the error I am experiencing.

Comment: fwiw, a difference I can see in our setups is that we have a seperate solution with just the iOS project in it specifically which we use in an iOS only pipeline. (hence only the xcode and Xamarin.iOS demands).  I don't know if that will help at all, but it might be something worth trying in the process of elimination.  Other than that, I'm out of ideas and hopefully someone wiser in the ways of azure devops can step in :)